# How can I embed php code snippets in a string and have them properly interpreted using Symfony-v2.8?

Tags: php, html, embed, symfony-2.8

I have a web-page that is created by server-side a php script that uses the Symfony-2.8 framework.  I'm not using twige, but instead using the **$strMAIN** string variable to collect the content of the HTML page that is to be displayed in the user's browser.

I'm not sure if this is the cause or not, but I often use HereDoc statements so that the html content is more easily read when I edit the page content, and when I need to pass' php variables into the HTML content I generally use:

**${*variable*}**

Note, In the code examples shown below I wasn't able to use < and > characters in all of the normal places where these characters occur because the characters that followed wouldn't show properly, so I substituted **＜** for **<** and **＞** for **>**, so these substitutions are not the cause of the issue I'm asking about.

This works:

```
＜?php
$strMAIN = <<<"MAIN"
                    <script>
                      var guid = '${guid}';
                    </script>
MAIN;
return new Response( $strMAIN );
?＞
```

The above produces:

```
                    <script>
                      var guid = '234a4435435f...'; // The guid produced wasn't as shown.
                    </script>
```

However, I've see that values can also be 'passed into the HTML with using ＜?php echo $*variable*; ?＞ ,
but this doesn't work:

```
＜?php
$strMAIN = <<<'MAIN'
                    <script>
                      var guid = '＜?php echo $guid; ?＞';
                    </script>
MAIN;
return new Response( $strMAIN );
?＞
```

The above produces:

```
                    <script>
                      var guid = '＜?php echo $guid; ?＞';
                    </script>
```

How can I embed php code snippets in a string and have them properly interpreted using Symfony-v2.8?

Comment: in heredoc you can use php variables directly - [demo](https://3v4l.org/QcDGA)

Comment: I wish I could down vote this question, but it is locked.

Comment: Thanks, but in my question I showed that I'm aware of that.  What I'm trying to understand is how I might be able to use the <?php statement(s) ?> construct in a string expression or HereDoc.